# Retrieve the textview from ExpandableListAdapter

Tags: android

I want to retrieve the textview at a certain position of an ExpandableListView. Basically I have an expandable list view which contains headers and then the children, and the headers are basic textviews within the expandable listview.

What I need to do is to retrieve the header element from the expandable list view at a certain position and then change the text colour of that retrieved text view.

I've tried doing the following:

```
TextView textView = ((TextView)listAdapter.getGroupView(2, false, null, null).findViewById(R.id.listHeader));
            textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#fefefe"));
```

However, it doesn't seems to have any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I need to do is to retrieve the header element from the
>   expandable list view at a certain position and then change the text
>   colour of that retrieved text view.

The code you currently have will not work because you are creating a **new** view each time you call it and this view doesn't have any connection to the actual view from the `ExpandableListView`. And this would not be the right way to do it anyway because:

- you can only retrieve the currently visible row views
- changing the color at the view level will result in receiving that color for other rows as the view gets recycled

The proper way is to make the color change at the adapter's data level(have some sort of structure to hold the change or embedded it directly in the data itself) and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.